# How can I minimise window launching time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a stack to maintain list of windows. when I open any window that window name is added to stack and when I click on back button it delete the top element and then launch previous window, while going back it is showing some white color for a moment then launches the window. So how can I avoid this glitch.

I have tried managing UI element load on window as that window contains lots of UI element and animations.

```
StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            var type = method.DeclaringType;
            var name = method.Name;

            index = PathListType.Count - 1;

                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    if (ReturnStateHome)
                    {
                        for (int i = index; i > 0; i--)
                        {                           
                            PathListType.RemoveAt(i);
                            //  Remove the state
                            CloseBtnStateList.RemoveAt(i);                            
                            index = i - 1;
                        }
                        index = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        PathListType.RemoveAt(index);

                        CloseBtnStateList.RemoveAt(index);
                    }
//Code for launching windows

     if (typ == typeof(DemoLauncher)) { FrameData.IsPauseGesture = true; }

                        try
                        {
        //  Dynamically instantiate a class instance with specific type
                         Window wnd = (Window)Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
                         wnd.Show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                        }
```

I expect smooth transition between windows when launched from stack

Comment: Are you closing the windows? If you hide them then it would be quicker. And. What do you mean by "I have tried managing UI element load on window as that window contains lots of UI element and animations."  If you put a lot of processing in load then of course it'll take more work to load the window.

Comment: By the way. Have you considered a single window app rather than multi window? Just showing a window involves some animation and stuff. I prefer single window apps, partly because users can "lose" windows if you have a window per view.

Comment: Like Andy suggested, you can create a multiwindow look/feel with a tabcontrol by just hiding the tab header. Then switching windows is as simple as changing the tabindex.

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend you to use Components that already exist:

- you dont need to create a Stack there is a class from Microsoft [Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.8)
- and for all opened windows you got this collection here `App.Current.Windows`